# How to access Chrome active tab URL using Script Editor and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to write my first OS X script using JavaScript instead of AppleScript, and am running into some issues. The first part of this is to get the URL from a tab in Chrome, so that I can do some more work on it (e.g., create a new reading list item in safari). I've tried the following code:

```
var safari = Application('Safari');
var chrome = Application('Google Chrome');
chrome.activate();
var url = chrome.windows[0].tabs[0].get('url'); // This returns an ObjectSpecifier
safari.addReadingListItem(url, {andPreviewText: 'Added from Chrome'});
```

This fails, with error: "Error -1700: Can't convert types." I need a string, but this is still an Object specifier. So I guess I don't get a string back from `.get('url')`

I haven't had any luck finding examples of pulling values FROM the scripting environment, but I've seen a few about putting new tabs into a browser. Any help with this is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

To get the URL of the *active* tab, do:

```
Application('Chrome').windows[0].activeTab.url()
```

Answer (score -1):

After more digging, I tracked down what you're supposed to do. Documented here: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW8)

Properties are returned as object specifiers, to get a value from an object specifier, you call it like a function:

```
chrome.windows[0].tabs[0].url(); // the string value of the URL
```

Settable properties can be set using the `=`. This does not apply to read-only values (which are marked as such in the Library Panel in script editor:

```
chrome.windows[0].tabs[0].url = "http://example.com";
```

Comment: This does not answer your own question. It gets the URL of the first tab, not of the active one.

Comment: Considering I asked the question, and it works for me now, I suppose I'd be the judge of correctness? Next time, ask for clarification... I really meant any tab, but mentioned 'active' as an example. The actual problem, if you read more carefully, is with handling `url`, not which tab.